# What is the dual of $l^p$ for $0<p<1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, dual-spaces

$l^p$ for $1\leq p<\infty$ is defined as the vector space on which $$x\mapsto\sqrt[p]{\sum_j{|x_j|^p}}$$ is a norm.  For $0<p<1$, this cannot be a norm, but (as Wiki [indicates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space#%E2%84%93p_spaces)) the function $$\mapsto\sum_j{|x_j|^p}$$ is still a metric, so it's a (complete) topological vector space.

If $1\leq p<\infty$, the dual of $l^p$ is well-known to be $l^q$, where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$.  **What is the (topological) dual of $l^p$ for $0<p<1$?**

In that case, $l^p\subseteq l^1$, so $l^{\infty}\subseteq(l^p)^*$.  But I don't know what else is in there.

Comment: A big problem with $L^p$ spaces for $0<p<1$ is that sometimes they don't have enough open convex sets. For instance, it can happen that the only open convex subset is $L^p$ itself; this implies that the space has no continuous linear functionals (in particular it's dual is $\{ 0\}$). I'm not sure this is the case here, but it's something to keep in mind, especially considering your last line.

Comment: The dual of $l^p$ for $0 < p < 1$ is $l^\infty$. See Theorem 6 in  https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf1/euclid.bams/1183503236.  For $L^p[0,1]$ when $0 < p < 1$, the dual space is $0$: see Theorem 1 of that  same paper or see https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/lpspace.pdf.

Comment: @KCd: That sounds like an answer....